# What is best cyclic graph representation to be kind to Java GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Or I might ask with newer GCs does it matter?

If it does then is it desirable to manage links between nodes through a lookup table or using weak references ( yet more memory ), or is it fine just to have all the nodes point to each other.  This is assuming I have a "dispose" method where node or link removal sets all references to it to null.

The issue is if there is a large database in ram, would it be a drastic hit on GC performance if it has to evaluate a lot of long random cycles in the graph? or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *mark and sweep* approach to garbage collection is totally insensitive to the topology of object graphs. As soon as it reaches an already marked object, it assumes all its referents are marked as well, so you can't do much harm no matter how you design your structure.

My advice is to be obsessive about keeping your code as natural a fit to the problem as possible, and quite lax about any other concerns. When you hit a real performance/memory problem, only then comes a time when you stop and think about optimization.

Comment: good to know I would have thought there was some overhead in determining whether a memory value was a handle or data, and that might have involved having to traverse the topology in some way.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be rather disappointing if Java's GC was broken by cyclic references. Fortunately, it's not. I didn't understand the database part of your question though. I think it would help a lot if you'd get a bit more specific about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I know :) 
the guestion was whether large cyclic graphs impacted GC performance in any way with the typical Java VM's garbage collectors.  Such things as keeping parent pointers in children in trees, etc.  I often see comments and posts to the effect that such things impact performance and this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

HotSpot VM's garbage collectors don't use reference counting. There are either **mark/sweep/compact** collectors or **copy collectors**, both of which traverse the object graph (here meaning the graph of all the Java objects in the JVM) from its roots (local variables on the call stacks of all the active threads, static fields etc.).

Basically, whenever an object is not **reachable** from any of the roots, then it's simply **dead**, no matter how many other dead objects reference it. Dead in this context doesn't actually mean that the object's memory has already been freed, it only says that the object will be reclaimed (deleted) by the GC during its next run.

In simple words, all the objects that the GC visits during the graph traversal are *alive*, all the other are *dead*.

So whenever you null all external references to your graph structure, then the whole graph structure will be garbage collected, no matter how many internal references it keeps.

Here is a nice explanation of **mark & sweep** algorithm by Bob Lee:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTC0g14ImPc#t=177s
and later in the same video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTC0g14ImPc#t=2917s

Comment: "Whenever [...] then [...]" makes it sound like the GC will be immediate, when it's not, the graph structure only becoming eligible to be GCed. I'd rephrase it a bit more clearly.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I haven't explained very clearly what "dead" actually means in this context.